# How to Call function in the webview html href onClick in appcelerator titanium

Tags: function, webview, href, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have webview in the html i have showing the multiple links in each link i want to call the javascript function.But the javascript function is not calling please help how to resolve this.Thanks in advance.
below is my code.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor : '#fff'
});
var webViewTesting = Ti.UI.createWebView({
  height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
  width : Ti.UI.FILL,
  html : "<html><body><p>Hi Nice Hair Style By <a href='#' onclick='displayUserDetails();'>Raju</a><a href='#' onclick='displayUserDetails();'>Jon Hills</a></body></html>",
});

win.add(webViewTesting);

function  displayUserDetails(){
  Ti.API.info('displayUserDetails');    
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Ti.App.fireEvent`, in your .html :

```
<a href="#" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('action');">Test</a>
```

Then, in your index.js for example :

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('action', function(){
    //do something
});
```

edit, change your code to :

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor : '#fff'
});
var webViewTesting = Ti.UI.createWebView({
  height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
  width : Ti.UI.FILL,
  html : '<html><body><p>Hi Nice Hair Style By <a href="#" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('displayUserDetails');">Raju</a><a href="#" onclick="Ti.App.fireEvent('displayUserDetails');">Jon Hills</a></body></html>"
});

win.add(webViewTesting);

Ti.App.addEventListener('displayUserDetails', function(){
  //do something
  Ti.API.info("displayUserDetails');    
});
```

Comment: HI Thomas, Thanks for giving quick reply,i have tried the above approach but in my index.js that fire event listener is not firing in my js file please help me.

Comment: Is it possible in index.js file i have  webview i am taking the html property in that i have multiple href links in each link i want to call the function

Comment: I've change my answer, you can try the new code i've post ?